# Программно создать метод нажатия на Label'ы

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо создать несколько (заранее неизвестно сколько) label'ов и для каждого определить метод нажатия. Всё это должно происходить циклически.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        flag1 = true;

        ReadXMLDocument("new.xml", "Управление проектами");

        arrLabel[] la = new arrLabel[arrLength];

        int length, floor, column, row;
        floor = length = 20;
        column = row = 0;

        tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
        tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i)
        {
            la[i] = new arrLabel(result[i], countRes[i]);
            la[i].lbl.Size = new Size(160, 20);
            la[i].lbl.Location = new Point(floor, length);
            la[i].lbl.AutoSize = true;
            la[i].lbl.Click() = (sender, args) => la[i].action();
            tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(la[i].lbl, column, row);

            if (floor < 400)
            {
                floor += 150;
            }
            else
                length += 20;

            if (column == 4)
            {
                row++;
                column = 0;
            }
            else
                column++;

            Console.WriteLine(column + " " + row);

        }
```

Comment: А как вы создаёте один Label? Сделайте то же самое в цикле.

Comment: В том-то и проблема: я не знаю, как сделать это программно даже для одного элемента. Если вы приведете коротенький пример буду премного благодарен.

Comment: `var label = new Label();
label.Click += (s,e) => MessageBox.Show("Вуаля!");`

Comment: Так и знал, что нужно использовать +=... Спасибо большое!

Comment: А эта конструкция точно верная? Выводит ошибку "Click может находиться только в левой части операции +="

Comment: `Click` то без скобочек писать надо, когда событие подключаете.

Вот так:

`  la[i].lbl.Click = (sender, args) => la[i].action();`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам пример, скопипастил из [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx):

```
const double X = 10, startY = 10, labelVerticalSpacing = 20;
const int numberOfLabels = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLabels; i++)
{
    var labelNumber = i; // не попадаемся на проблему с замыканием
    var label = new Label()
    {
        Location = new Point(X, startY + i * labelVerticalSpacing),
        Text = "label #" + i
    };
    label.Click += (sender, args) => ProcessLabelClick(labelNumber);
    this.Controls.Add(label);
}

void ProcessLabelClick(int labelNumber)
{
    // здесь произошёл клик на label c номером labelNumber, обрабатываем.
}
```

Comment: Нет там такого примера :)

Comment: Ну, там половина этого примера :-) Я ж на Winforms ни разу не писал, скажу вам по секрету.

Comment: Ругается на то, что Click может находится только в левой части, хотя он и находится слева)

Comment: @Сергей1991: Странно. Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Привел код, большая часть не имеет отношения к проблеме.

Comment: @Сергей1991: А откуда у вас после Click скобки взялись? :-P

Comment: Всё моя невнимательность. :D Спасибо вам большое.

Comment: Теперь возникает исключительная ситуация IndexOutOfRangeException и выделен фрагмент la[i].action() в строчке la[i].lbl.Click += (sender, args) => la[i].action(). Причем ситуация возникает не во время заполнения массива (в конструкторе), а именно после нажатия на данный label.

Comment: @Сергей1991: а вы сделайте как в моём примере, видите трюк с `labelNumber`? Вы тоже попались на [проблему с замыканием](http://stackoverflow.com/q/271440/276994).